# IBM SecureRandom on Eclipse Kepler RTC plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-kepler, rtc

I have some difficult to connect to my project area.
It appears when i want to connect an error :

> XXXXXXXXXX Failed to log into 'XXX.XXXX' Could not create
>   IBMSecureRandom  Could not create IBMSecureRandom  IBMSecureRandom
>   SecureRandom not available

happen.

I dont know how to soluce that, i use the RTC plugin 3.0.2 (i need to use this one especially)

If you have an idea or if you can enlight me it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for this one.
And its not that hard.

So first, i wanted to test with another workspace and connect on the same repository. And it worked well.

I just added the -clean command on the execution path, launch Eclipse and the problem was solve.

Hope it can help other people.